# 補助線を出力したい

Tags: chart.js

chart.jsを利用してフラグ作成をしています。
一定間隔で　主線（実線）：10間隔　と　副線（破線）：５間隔　を表示したいのですが、
どのようにしたら良いでしょうか。下記のようにminorを利用したのですがうまくいきません。

```
<!-- メモリ設定 -->
, ticks: {
 fontColor: "#0040FF"<!-- 縦軸の値の色 -->
 ,min:0
 ,max:100
 ,stepSize:10
 ,minor: {
    fontColor: "pink"<!-- 縦軸の値の色 -->
    ,stepSize:5
    , borderDash :[5, 7]    <!-- 破線 -->
 }
 , major: {
    fontColor: "white"<!-- 縦軸の値の色 -->
    ,stepSize:10
 }
}
```